# jQuery removeAttr blocks re-adding the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes that I want people to be able to tick individually, or bulk tick/untick for ease of use.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="c1" /> <label for="cl">Category</label>
```

The markup for the buttons to bulk tick/untick them is:

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="tick-all">Tick All</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="untick-all">Un-Tick All</a>
</p>
```

and the JavaScript is:

```
$("#tick-all").click(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', 'checked');
});

$("#untick-all").click(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');
});
```

but when I click the buttons in the order: `tick, untick, tick`, then they will only work the first two times, and after that, the checkboxes won't become ticked again.

Comment: Use `.prop('checked', true);` and `.prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with `prop()` instead of `attr`

```js
$("#tick-all").click(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
});

$("#untick-all").click(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="c1" /> <label for="cl">Category</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="c1" /> <label for="cl">Category</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="c1" /> <label for="cl">Category</label>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="tick-all">Tick All</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="untick-all">Un-Tick All</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', true);
$("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
```

or

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

User Jquery Prop method like below

```
$("#tick-all").click(function () {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
});

$("#untick-all").click(function () {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked',false);
});
```